# How to calculate with money fields? Like extracting discount percentage

Tags: fieldtypes

Maybe I'm overlooking something, but can't find a solution on the interwebs..

I have 2 (money) fields: product.price and product.oldPrice

When I try to calculate the discount like this (I'm aware that this simple approach shouldn't work):

```
{% set discount = product.price / product.oldPrice * 100 %}
```

I get this error message:
***Unsupported operand types: Money\Money / Money\Money***

And when I try calling it as a 'float':

```
{% set discount = product.price|number_format(2) / product.oldPrice|number_format(2) * 100 %}
```

I get this error message:
***Object of class Money\Money could not be converted to float***

The only solution I can think of is changing the field type in '***Float***', but that would make things more difficult.

I also tried Martin Spains solution, who suggested to call the value of the objects like this:

```
{% set discount = product.price.value / product.oldPrice.value * 100 %}
```

But then I get this error:

*Neither the property "value" nor one of the methods "value()", "getvalue()"/"isvalue()"/"hasvalue()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Money\Money".*

I hope someone has a solution for me

Comment: I've not used Money fields before, but I wonder if you might need to access the value of the field like this: `product.price.value` to get the value itself rather than the field model.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSpain! I gave it a try, but unfortunately without any luck. Check my updated post

Answer (score 2):

As always, for anything non-trivial, you're probably better off writing a Twig extension to abstract your logic to PHP...

That said, for "quick and dirty" calculations, Money objects have an `amount` property that will give you the value (but as a string, and in cents). It's pretty easy to parse that to something more useful though:

```
{# get the value of a money field as a float #}
{% set value = moneyField.amount | float / 100 %}
```

You can then do whatever math operations you need to do, before piping through the `currency` filter for formatting:

```
{{ value | currency('USD') }}
```

You can also use the Money object's `currency` property if you need to dynamically determine the currency from the field:

```
{{ value | currency(moneyField.currency) }}
```